# Mojave, High Sierra, and Sierra performance on MacBook Pro 9,1 (15 mid-2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra, mojave

**My computer:**
MacBook Pro 9,1 (15" mid-2012), 2.6 GHz i7, 16 GB RAM, 256GB OWC SSD, NVIDIA GT 650M (~1GB)

El Capitan is no longer supported for some of the software I need to use, so it looks like I have to update to Sierra, High Sierra, or Mojave. I'm always remiss to update to a newer Apple OS on older hardware because it frequently results in performance dips on the machine.

From what I've read Mojave doesn't run well on this model of MBP because it leans into the GPU, and wasn't really designed to play nice with NVIDIA graphics cards. Technically it's supported, but poorly according to user reports. I've heard mixed reports about High Sierra, some saying it resulted in improved performance and battery life, others saying their system became sluggish. By all accounts Sierra was a mess, and should be avoided.

I'm wondering if anyone with a similar MBP has any experience running Mojave, High Sierra, or Sierra, and what their feedback is. Which OS will run smoothest on this model of MBP?